# Not Able to Merge Rerun Failure Report Of Robot Framework while running Multiple Suites using Pabot

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to run the multiple suites in the single run using pabot. Test is running fine, but when I am trying to rerun the failure process get exits with below error message.
ParseError: mismatched tag: line 522, column 2
On further debugging I also notices that output.xml and rerun.xml are not some because all suites are not executed as some are 100% passed. Please refer the attached snapshot of the report.

Shell I am using to run suites is

```
root@ankit:~#cat pabotexecuter.sh
testcases=( $@ )
len=${#testcases[@]}
echo $testcases
release=${testcases[$len-2]}
build=${testcases[$len-1]}
tcList=${testcases[@]:0:$len-2}
tim=`date +"%T"`
mon=`date +"%F"`
rd="$mon-$tim"
`pabot --processes 1 -M Build-$release-$build -d /path/results/$rd -o output.xml $tcList`
```

Shell I am using to rerun and merge

```
root@ankit:~#cat rerunpabotexecuter.sh
path=$1
suitName=$2
`pabot --rerunfailed $path/output.xml --output $path/rerun.xml /path/results/2020-08-14-11:25:44 /path/testcases/D***.robot /path/M***.robot /path/N***.robot /path/R****.robot /path/SP***.robot`

#post processing
rebot --outputdir $path --merge $path/output.xml $path/rerun.xml
```

But if I run single suite everything work fine, but please let me know how to successfully implement this structure so that I can also rerun multiple suites together

[Robot Suites Run Status Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7eLE.png)